# How to tell if Netsuite is in View/Edit Mode?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Is there a way to tell if we are in edit or view mode for a netsuite record? I tried using the executionContext, but that was the same whether it was view or edit, so that didn't work. I just want to hide some fields if I am in edit mode, and show them if I am in view. I am using suitescript 2.0.

Thanks

Comment: The record mode is passed in via the parameter that gets passed in to your event handler. Which event type are you using? Then I can be more specific.

Comment: I'm in the user event script before load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mode gets passed in to the `beforeLoad` event via the `type` property. The value is an enum of `context.UserEventType`.

```js
function beforeLoad(context) {
  if (context.type === context.UserEventType.EDIT) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Check the NS Help pages "beforeLoad(scriptContext)" and "context.UserEventType" for reference details.